# what is the difference between "* and "+?

Tags: register, expression-register

The two registers `"*` and `"+`, what is the difference between them?

Maybe they are all about OS clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

`"*` is for `PRIMARY` buffer/store/selection in X11 world and `"+` is for `CLIPBOARD`.
There are 3 separate selections for X11 apps to use for data exchange:

- PRIMARY
- SECONDARY
- CLIPBOARD

Vim uses only `PRIMARY` and `CLIPBOARD`. You can read more in Vim's help: `:h x11-selection`.

You can also `set clipboard=unnamedplus`, which will alias `"*` register to `"+` (`:h clipboard-unnamedplus`, [Using the clipboard as the default register](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard))

I'm not sure how it exactly works on Windows and Mac, since there is no such separation as in Linux/X11

Comment: IIRC on mac the behavior is similar to setting clipboard to unnamedplus; it uses `pbcopy` i believe.